# strictly positive elements under a nonzeo $*$ homomorphism

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a separable $C^*$ algebra,x is a strictly positive element in $A$,$\phi:A\rightarrow B$ is a nonzero $*$ homomorphism,is $\phi(x)$ also strictly positive in$B$?

Comment: In general, if $A \subseteq B$ and $a \in A$ is strictly positive, then $a$ might not be strictly postive in $B$, e.g. non-unital inclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Take $\phi:C([0,1])\to C([0,1]\cup\{2\})$ to be the map such that $(\phi f)(t)=f(t)$ whenever $t\in[0,1]$ and $(\phi f)(2)=0$ for all $f\in C([0,1])$.  Then any element in the image of $\phi$ is non-invertible, hence not strictly positive.